# Testing ProfileHandlers in self-hosting scenario

Tags: nservicebus

My team and I are currently working on a services framework and are struggling with how to best handle integration tests.  Currently, we are self-hosting NServiceBus which was fine to a point; however, now we would like to bootstrap the framework using NServiceBus Profiles/ProfileHandlers.  I am not aware of how to specify profiles in a self-hosted scenario, or if that's even possible.  We thought to use the Generic Host, but I don't really see how that would work in a testing scenario since the host needs its own process (to my knowledge anyway).

Basically, I'm wondering if my assumptions above are correct, and if so, how have others worked around these issues.

Answer (score 0):

We're running unit tests via the test framework provided within NSB(NServiceBus.Testing.dll).  Everything here is done in memory locally.  Do use infrastructure we just use the generic host on the command line.  This does not require you to install a Windows Service.  Just run NServiceBus.Host.exe from the command line with your specified profile.  I you want to spin up a bunch of these, a simple script should do.